# react native console.debug does not show log using log-ios

Tags: react-native

After upgrading the existing project to react native v 0.48.3, console.debug is not listing logs when I run the application on the simulator.
It used to work till I upgraded using the `react-native upgrade` option.

Any suggestion to view the logs using `react-native log-ios`. I am able to view logs on the Chrome console though, if I run the remote debugger.

```
React native version: 0.48.3
iOS = macOS Sierra 10.12.6.
```

react-native log-ios shows

```
Scanning 597 folders for symlinks in /Users/James/workspace/ReactNative/my_app/node_modules (4ms)
NOTE:  Most system logs have moved to a new logging system.  See log(1) for more information.
Sep 25 21:36:29 DSSB1234 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.57E26096-292C-4C40-9A7A-D0E1092F482C[1625] (com.apple.videosubscriptionsd[2757]) : Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Sep 25 21:36:29 DSSB1234 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.57E26096-292C-4C40-9A7A-D0E1092F482C[1625] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) : Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 25 21:36:29 DSSB1234 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.57E26096-292C-4C40-9A7A-D0E1092F482C[1625] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) : Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Sep 25 21:36:29 DSSB1234 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.57E26096-292C-4C40-9A7A-D0E1092F482C[1625] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) : Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 25 21:36:29 DSSB1234 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.57E26096-292C-4C40-9A7A-D0E1092F482C[1625] (com.apple.AssetCacheLocatorService) : Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 25 21:36:29 DSSB1234 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.57E26096-292C-4C40-9A7A-D0E1092F482C[1625] (com.apple.AssetCacheLocatorService) : Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 25 21:36:29 DSSB1234 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.57E26096-292C-4C40-9A7A-D0E1092F482C[1625] (com.apple.StreamingUnzipService) : Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 25 21:36:29 DSSB1234 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.57E26096-292C-4C40-9A7A-D0E1092F482C[1625] (com.apple.StreamingUnzipService) : Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 25 21:36:33 DSSB1234 my_app[2763] : assertion failed: 16G29 15A372: libxpc.dylib + 69578 [D870A237-D3A7-31F5-AAD4-CE880C0C8E7B]: 0x7d
Sep 25 21:36:33 DSSB1234 Unknown[2763] :
```

Comment: I prefer "React Native Debugger". It's awesome https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger :)

Comment: We have the same issue, but the "Debug JS Remotely" option means we almost never have to read logs this way as they show up just fine in Chrome's console. For release builds (or debug builds which we don't want to run on Chrome) we so far always managed to find the logs by opening the "Console" app that ships with Mac OS (the simulator will show up as a device there, you can them filter log lines based on your app's name as there will be a lot of stuff.

Comment: You should have a look at https://github.com/Annihil/react-native-log-ios, it does not require remote JS debugging, basically just use the `log` command of OSX!

Comment: If you using React Native above 61 it will automatically show in your terminal without debugging. WHat version React Native you used?.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem. Logging has been working fine in Dev mode and all of a sudden, no console.log output to stdout in the console window of the react-native log-ios. However, I can see the messages in the IOS simulator under the Debug > Open System Log.

Answer (score 0):

By default on iOS, it logs to the debug pane inside Xcode.
From the iOS simulator, press (⌘+D) and press Remote JS Debugging. This will open a resource, http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui on localhost. From there, use the Chrome Developer tools JavaScript console to view console.log